# Java: Easiest way to replace strings with random strings

Tags: java, regex, replace

A string will be made up of certain symbols (ax,bx,dx,c,acc for example) and numbers.

ex:
ax 5 5
dx 3 acc
c ax bx

I want to replace one or all of the symbols (randomly) with another symbol of the same set. ie, replace one of {ax,bx,dx,c,acc} with one of {ax,bx,dx,c,acc}.

replacement example:
acc 5 5
dx 3 acc
c ax bx
or
c 5 5
dx 3 acc
c ax ax

Is there a way to do this with regexes? In Java? If so, which methods should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the most clean solution for replacing a certain set of symbols from a string containing a superset of them.
appendreplacement is the key to this method.
one important caveat: do not include any unescped dollar characters ($) in your elements list. escape them by using "\$"
eventually use
    .replaceall("\$","\\$");
on every string before adding it to the list.
see also the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)) in doubt about the $ signs.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class ReplaceTokens {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> elements = Arrays.asList("ax", "bx", "dx", "c", "acc");
    final String patternStr = join(elements, "|"); //build string "ax|bx|dx|c|acc" 
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
    Matcher m = p.matcher("ax 5 5 dx 3 acc c ax bx");
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Random rand = new Random();
    while (m.find()){
        String randomSymbol = elements.get(rand.nextInt(elements.size()));
        m.appendReplacement(sb,randomSymbol);
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println(sb);
}

/**
 * this method is only needed to generate the string ax|bx|dx|c|acc in a clean way....
 * @see org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join    for a more common alternative...
 */
public static String join(List<String> s, String delimiter) {
    if (s.isEmpty()) return "";
    Iterator<String> iter = s.iterator();
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(iter.next());
    while (iter.hasNext()) buffer.append(delimiter).append(iter.next());
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first question: no.

Since you are doing a random replace, regex will not help you, nothing about regex is random. * Since your strings are in an array, you don't need to find them with any pattern matching, so again regex isn't necessary.

**Edit: the question has been edited so it no longer says the strings are in an array. In this case, assuming they are all in one big string, you might build a regex to find the parts you want to replace, as shown in other answers.*

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Random](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class to generate a random int to choose the index of the symbols.

```
    String text = "ax 5 5 dx 3 acc c ax bx";
    System.out.println("Original: " + text);
    String[] tokens = text.split(" ");
    List<Integer> symbols = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            symbols.add(i);
        }
    }
    Random rand = new Random();
    // this is the part you can do multiple times
    int source = symbols.get((rand.nextInt(symbols.size())));
    int target = symbols.get((rand.nextInt(symbols.size())));
    tokens[target] = tokens[source];

    String result = tokens[0];
    for(int i=1; i<tokens.length; i++) {
        result = result + " " + tokens[i];
    }
    System.out.println("Result: " + result);
```

Make as many replacements as you need *before* you [join](http://hivemind.apache.org/hivemind1/hivemind/apidocs/org/apache/hivemind/util/StringUtils.html) the tokens back together.

There are two parts here that might seem tricky.  First, the try catch to identify those tokens that are not integers.  I recommend you pull that part out into its own method, since it works, but it's a bit hacky.

The second is where I set the `source` and `target` variables.  What I'm doing there is getting a randomly selected *index* of one of the non-numeric symbols.  Once I have two random indexes, I can swap them in the next line.

An alternative would be, to build up a new String from randomly selected symbols after you've split the original String into an array.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, this can be done with regexes. 
   Probably not very prettily, not
   without a loop or two
2. Yes, this can be implemented in Java.
3. See [Random](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), the [regex](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex) package
4. The implementation is left as an exercise for the student.

Answer (score -1):

thanks a bunch guys. here's what i came up with. see if you can come up with a more efficient way.

```
private final String[] symbolsPossible = {"ax","bx","cx","dx","foo"};
private boolean exists;
private final String mutate(String s)
{
String[] tokens=s.split(" ");
for(int j=0; j<tokens.length; j++)
if(Math.random()<.1) //10% chance of mutation per token
{
//checking to see if the token is a supported symbol
exists=false;
for(int i=0; i<symbolsPossible.length; i++)
    if(tokens[j].equals(symbolsPossible[i]))
       exists=true;
if(exists)
    tokens[j]=symbolsPossible[(int)Math.random()*symbolsPossible.length];
}
StringBuffer result=new StringBuffer();
for(String t:tokens)
    result.append(t);
return result;
}
```